# Vim Align Python Arguments with Tabularize

Tags: python, vim, vim-tabular

How can I align my python arguments quickly in Vim. New to tabular plugin and cannot figure out command for aligning arguments properly:

Have this:

```
myfunc(arg1=value1,
       arg2=value2,
 arg3=value3,
       arg4=value4,
   arg5=value5,
   arg6=value6,
   arg7=value7)
```

Want this:

```
myfunc(arg1=value1,
       arg2=value2,
       arg3=value3,
       arg4=value4,
       arg5=value5,
       arg6=value6,
       arg7=value7)
```

Comment: Could this question be moved to http://vi.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need Tabular.vim for this. Put your cursor at the top of `myfunc` (or a bit higher) and press `=}` (or `=)`). This runs `equalprg` across your function block to indent it appropriately.

From the help on `'equalprg'`:

> External program to use for "=" command.  When this option is empty
>   the internal formatting functions are used; either 'lisp', 'cindent'
>   or 'indentexpr'.  When Vim was compiled without internal formatting,
>   the "indent" program is used.
>   Environment variables are expanded |:set_env|.  See |option-backslash|
>   about including spaces and backslashes.
>   This option cannot be set from a |modeline| or in the |sandbox|, for
>   security reasons.

BTW, if you do want to learn more about Tabular and its use cases, there’s a [great video on vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/).